# Disable the "disable" option for Networking in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

If you right click the network icon in the system tray in Windows Server 2003, right next to "Status" is "Disable".

If you "misclick" this, the result can be catastrophic. Is there a way to disable it, or remove it from the list to avoid "accidently" clicking it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give user the admin access, then they shouldn't be able to mess with network settings.

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your problem: disable the "show icon in cotification area" option when right clicking the netwok connection in the control panel; instead, have a link to the network connection in the "quick links" area which single clicking gives you the status option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

Open network connections. Right click and select 'properties' of your connection and on the general tab at the bottom there are two check boxes for 'show icon in notification area when connected' and 'notify me when this connection has limited or no connectivity'
UNcheck these two boxes